# Is speed a factor in diagonal traversal?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

In response to [the following Reddit post](http://lf.reddit.com/r/PuzzleAndDragons/comments/2xj8oq/psadiscuss_diagonal_orb_movement/):

> "[I]f you're struggling with diagonals this is what I found [...]: It's all in the SPEED. Accuracy doesn't seem to have that big of a part [i]n it. [...]
>
> The margin of error you have to complete a diagonal is pretty large(on my Galaxy S4 I could be off by about 2-3mm from the center of the orb/diagonal and still have it register), but as long as you move quick, the game seems to "auto-register" the movement as a diagonal. The best way I can describe it is a "flick" of your thumb."

Does speed actually factor into diagonal orb movement?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the key to moving orbs diagonally, is to swipe really fast on your screen.
According to the following links:
*http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Mechanics
*http://puzzleanddragonsforum.com/archive/index.php?thread-5469.html
*http://www.reddit.com/r/PuzzleAndDragons/comments/1ztjs3/so_how_many_of_you_are_capable_of_doing_diagonal/

I normally diagonal swipe when I'm rushing through a big combo. But I only succeed 2/5 of the time.